# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

Estoy realizando una parte de código en vite junto con reactJS.
Tengo un error en la parte de poder hacer uso de `importKey`, no se que mas falte para poder hacer uso de ello.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 const keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
'raw',
encoder.encode(contraseña),
{ name: 'PBKDF2' },
    false,
    ['deriveKey']
)
```

Teniendo por error la parte del `crypto.subtle.importKey()`.

Una parte importante es que `vite` no me deja poner esta parte:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

Ya que al trabajar en `vite` marca el siguiente error:

```
caught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

No se que sucede que bloquea todo el uso de `require`.